# WebDav и libreoffice 5.3.4 не приходит PUT запрос от libreoffice

Tags: java, spring-mvc, open-office, webdav, libre-office

Есть связка приложение на java,spring, реализовываю функционал позволяющий из приложения по клику на ссылку документа(.../webdav/id/document_name.odt) открыть документ в libreoffice, отредактировать документ и после сохранения записать его в нашу бд.

На данный момент работает открытие документа. 
Как это происходит, со стороны сервера написан простой сервлет(https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-webdav step-1) который обрабатывает запросы отсылаемые libreoffice-ом серверу(PROPFIND,OPTIONS,GET),
когда сервер получает запрос PROPFIND в ответ пишу XML

```
<multistatus xmlns="DAV:">
<response>
    <href>http://localhost:8080/julia/webdav/287/TI-5-1.odt</href>
    <propstat>
        <prop>
            <resourcetype/>
            <getcontenttype>application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text</getcontenttype>
        </prop>
        <status>HTTP/1.1 200 OK</status>
    </propstat>
    <propstat>
        <prop>
            <IsReadOnly/>
            <supportedlock/>
        </prop>
        <status>HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found</status>
    </propstat>
</response>
```

когда получаем GET пишем в ответе сам файл(byte[]) из бд.
когда получаем OPTIONS в ответ пишем вот такие заголовки: 
"DAV", "1, 2, ordered-collections"
"Allow", "OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, COPY, MOVE, MKCOL, PROPFIND, PROPPATCH, LOCK, UNLOCK, ORDERPATCH"
"MS-Author-Via", "DAV"
После этого офис открывает наш файл и мы можем его редактировать.

Так вот сама проблема, если отредактировать файл в либреофисе и попытаться его сохранить, на сервер НЕ приходит PUT или POST запрос с данными изменённого в либроофисе документа, приходят только запросы PROPFIND, OPTIONS, HEAD

Comment: тот же вопрос тут https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/123847/connect-libreoffice-534-with-application-using-webdav/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге не в ту сторону копал и нашёл достаточно простое решение https://github.com/ceefour/webdav-servlet